# Why can't I control window level of NSPopover called from menulet?

Tags: cocoa, nspopover

I'm another one trying to make application showing itself in popover relative to system status bar menulet.
I'm trying to avoid custom classes and using base NSPopover.

It works fine, **except its window's level — I can not control it**, so my popover appears over everything: Notification center and Spot Lite, and Mission Control does not effect it.

[image]

**Here is my sample code** (from https://github.com/efojs/statusbarPopover):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

// Adding menulet _POP_ to status bar
self.myItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[self.myItem setAction:@selector(showPopover:)];
[self.myItem setTitle:@"_POP_"];
[self.myItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[self.myItem setTarget:self];
[self.myItem setEnabled:YES];
}

-(void) showPopover:(id)sender {

// Click POP to see Popover

NSViewController *controller = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:nil];
NSPopover *popover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
[popover setContentViewController:controller];
[popover setAnimates:NO];
[popover.contentViewController.view.window setLevel:NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
                                                //    NSDockWindowLevel
                                                //    NSFloatingWindowLevel
                                                //    NSMainMenuWindowLevel
                                                //    NSNormalWindowLevel
                                                //    NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel
                                                //    NSScreenSaverWindowLevel
                                                //    NSStatusWindowLevel
                                                //    NSSubmenuWindowLevel
                                                //    NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel

// Showing the Popover
[popover showRelativeToRect:self.myItem.button.frame ofView:self.myItem.button preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];

// Run Mission Control while Popover is open to see the problem
// It neither moves as window nor disappears as panel

// If you can solve it, please mail to the.efojs@gmail.com

}
```

Could you please be so kind and help me understand if I can fix it and how?

Comment: My guess is that, when it shows, it sets its level to the level of the window of the view that it's relative to. For a status item button, that will be `NSStatusWindowLevel`. Try moving the setting of the level to after you show it.